# Compiling with MS C++17 a simulink model

Tags: matlab, visual-c++, simulink

I have a simulink model that makes use of truth data (lookup tables). When I attempt to compile the model into a binary (slrt), I get the following output :

> fatal error C1060: compiler is out of heap space
>
> NMAKE : fatal error
> U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.EXE"'
> : return code '0x2' Stop. The make command returned an error of 2
> 'An_error_occurred_during_the_call_to_make' is not recognized as an
> internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

While the size of the lookup table is definitely large (the order of 8 million elements). A point was made that previous model with similar size lookup tables have been compiled successfully.

I modified the generated .mk file and added /Zm2000 as an optimization flag. I get the same results

Any inputs ?

Comment: Beside /Zm - have you tried any of the other solutions suggested by : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/fatal-error-c1060?view=vs-2017 ?

Comment: @ToBe  I didn't because this is generated code from Simulink coder. It's already allocated dynamically. One of the generated files has a size of 1.5Gb